# real time lights and high quality shadows in webgl build

Tags: unity, performance, lighting, webgl, shadows

I have a game in which there are a lot of objects constantly moving around and a lot of real time lights with their setting set to highest, I'm building my game as webgl and this is costing me a lot of performance, how can I maintain the high quality and have better performance?

Comment: You realize that these are diametrically opposed, right?  Increasing quality decreases performance.  Decreasing quality increases performance.  You need to find the middle ground that works for your game.  Lower the polycount of 3D objects, lower the shadow quality or lighting quality.  If the lights don't move, you can bake them for some performance gain (realtime lights are a performance hit for sure), but there's always a trade off.

Comment: I do realize that @JesseWilliams but the quality is important for me I need the player to make some decisions based on the lights and shadows and the lights can move so I'm desperate right now